# Is the layout shift not considered in the current PageSpeed Insight lab data?

Tags: pagespeed-insights

if a website loads ads through client's (Ads service provider) interfaces. These ads are only displayed to customers who have an AdBlocker enabled, are using the Firefox browser or non Consent.

This ad loads only after the entire web page has been completely retrieved. This results in a "layout shift".
Q) Is this layout shift not considered in the current PageSpeed Insight lab data? Google Bot (PageSpeed Insight) is probably not running Adblocker or Firefox.

Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a programming question but one more suitable for https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

- Start the Google Developer tool in Chrome Browser (Ctrl+Shift+ I or F12 For Windows).
- Select the network tab.
- Reload the page.
- Check if those ads resources are loading or not. If yes then Google is taking those resources into account while calculating the PageSpeed score.

Comment: Thank you will sure try.. but its for firefox browser

Answer (score 0):

Is it considered in **lab data**? - probably not (depending on your timings).

However as far as the upcoming Core Web Vitals update it will still affect your score there.

You see Google will user the Chrome User Experience dataset (CrUX dataset) to determine your CLS etc.

The CrUX dataset is collected from real world users (who may be using an ad blocker!).

The big difference is that when collecting the Cumulative Layout Shift (CLS) data for the CrUX dataset Google actually monitors the page for Layout Shifts **until page unload**.

So if you have a layout shift at **any** point while someone is using the site it will affect your CLS score.

If you have enough traffic you can see this data under then "Origin Summary" and or "Field Data" sections on your Lighthouse report.